# Matched filter realization in voiceband modem?

Tags: filter, detection

As far as I understand, Adsl modems perform the signal detection with DSP-made matched filters.  How was the same thing done in voiceband modems, for example the 56k modem?

Comment: Ti introduced a DSP engine in one IC, about 1985. That was the time of the 56 modems.

Comment: "ADSL modems […] DSP-made matched filters": I wouldn't call OFDM a matched filter bank, considering the way things are handled, so I'd argue that your understanding is kind of questionable.